# How to inject Docker container build timestamp in container?

Tags: datetime, docker, dockerfile

I would like to build a container which shows up in its startup log its build datetime. Is there a way to have that information injected from my build machine into the container ?

Comment: how do you store your logs? Only console output, on a file (in the container or in the host), or in some db?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The output of each RUN step during a build is the changes to the filesystem. So you can output the date to a file in your image. And the logs from the container are just the stdout from commands you run. So you can cat out the date inside your entrypoint.

In code, you'd have at the end of your Dockerfile:

```
RUN date >/build-date.txt
```

And inside an entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#.... Initialization steps
echo Image built: $(cat /build-date.txt)
#.... More initialization steps
# run the command
exec "$@"
```

Comment: won't this RUN statement be cached?

Comment: @tkarls Yes, so it should be performed at the "end of your Dockerfile". If all lines before that are cached, the image didn't change, and the result of the build is the same image you already had before. If the previous line is not cached, that last RUN command will not be cached either.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to pass in the current build timestamp at build time.  You'd have to `docker build --build-arg build-date=$(date)` or something like that.  Having done that, you can refer to the argument using something similar to shell variable syntax at build time.

This is probably more useful if you have a significant build step in your Dockerfile (you're compiling a Go application) or if the metadata you're trying to embed is harder to generate programmatically (the source control version stamp, the name of the person running the build command).

Comment: Note that if you use a timestamp rather than a date, then your build will always rebuild fully.

You'll likely want to use date (as suggested) instead.

Comment: @BMitch's answer suggests injecting it at the _end_ of the `Dockerfile` for this reason.  [ARGs invalidate the cache on first use](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#impact-on-build-caching) of the defined variable, not at the point of the ARG definition.